# Why isn't this Angular dropdown directive that uses ng-options and controllerAs working?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm using Angular 1.4.7 and I'm trying to create a really simple directive that creates a dropdown. I think this may be an issue with my scope references in the ng-options but I'm not seeing where I'm going wrong.

```
angular
    .module('app', []);

angular.module('app')
       .directive('inventorytest', function () {
    return {
        template: '<select ng-options="inv.code as inv.desc for inv in ctrl.invTypes"></select>{{ctrl.sample}}',

        scope: {},
        controller: function () {
            this.invTypes = [
                { code: 'A', desc: 'Alpha' },
                { code: 'B', desc: 'Bravo' },
                { code: 'C', desc: 'Charlie' },
            ];
            this.sample = 'Hello';
        },
        controllerAs: 'ctrl'
    }
});
```

I see the sample variable getting bound, but not my dropdown. I think I have the syntax correct for this, but obviously something is wrong.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your missing `ng-model` on your select. That's how angular knows what to do with your selected value.

Ive tested this with Angular v1.2.1 however not v1.4.7 but it had the same behavior.

---

Also i believe `restrict` is needed which your missing also but i admit i could be wrong with that.

EDIT: That statement is incorrect, just found this in the docs:

> Note: When you create a directive, it is restricted to attribute and elements only by default. In order to create directives that are triggered by class name, you need to use the restrict option.

bit below this section: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#template-expanding-directive

---

So your directive is:

```
angular.module('app')
       .directive('inventorytest', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<select ng-model="selected" ng-options="inv.code as inv.desc for inv in ctrl.invTypes"></select>{{ctrl.sample}}. Selected: {{selected}}',

        scope: {},
        controller: function () {
            this.invTypes = [
                { code: 'A', desc: 'Alpha' },
                { code: 'B', desc: 'Bravo' },
                { code: 'C', desc: 'Charlie' },
            ];
            this.sample = 'Hello';
        },
        controllerAs: 'ctrl'
    }
});
```

See fiddle for it running: http://jsfiddle.net/nh9ntgoj/1/

Comment: Thanks. For testing I never would have caught that - I was just focused on getting the dropdown list binding working first.

Answer (score 1):

you are missing ng-model , look:

```
    angular
    .module('myApp', [])
     .directive('inventorytest', function () {
return {
    template: '{{ctrl.inv}} <select ng-model="ctrl.inv" ng-options="inv.code as inv.desc for inv in ctrl.invTypes"></select>',

    scope: {},
    controller: function () {
        this.invTypes = [
            { code: 'A', desc: 'Alpha' },
            { code: 'B', desc: 'Bravo' },
            { code: 'C', desc: 'Charlie' },
        ];
        this.sample = 'Hello';
        this.inv = ''
    },

    controllerAs: 'ctrl'
}
```

});